# Unusable 22.10 behaviour

Tags: unity, firefox, games, interface

I've had some problems since upgrading to 22.10, which have escalated in the past 2 weeks.

It started with Firefox, both normal and Nightly will suddenly freeze, but just the UI, the pages still work and I can use them normally, if I click on another tab, nothing happens, but if I switch to another app or alt-tab and come back it switches to the tab I clicked, Initially I thought it might be a problem with firefox, but I found nothing about it and now I'm not so sure, because now:

We come to problem number 2, that's been happening only for the last two weeks or so, in increasing frequency:

When I'm playing a game through Proton, the game sometimes will suddenly freeze for a moment, if firefox is open it will close by itself, with no crash message or anything, and will not open again until restarting, the game will look normal, but I won't be able to save, and the last save will be corrupted, and the weirdest of all: It also affects the Ubuntu system: after that happens, I'm not able to open a terminal at all, when I click the upper right menu the icons for screenshot, settings, and power sometimes are gone, but when they aren't, and I click to restart or power off nothing happens, it's like the UI still works but the system itself doesn't.

I already restarted with a fresh install and the problems still happen.

Here is a screenshot of what happens:
[image: img]

The Specs of the laptop:

```
i7-8700k
ROG Maximus X Code 
64GB DDR4
1080ti
```

My laptop is running a stripped-down version of Ubuntu 22.10 with no programs other than steam installed yet, both installed on a Samsung EVO NVME SSD.

Comment: I'm unable to form an image in my head about your problem.  Can you try to send a video of what happens if not then at least a detailed screenshot(Do not include sensitive information). At the moment the question is a bit unclear.

Comment: You provided no hardware information. There is no information to suggest anything.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/bYPs9uD (Here's a link of how that corner menu gets when that happens, will try taking a video when one of them happen.

Comment: Hardware: i7-8700k, ROG Maximus X Code, 64GB DDR4, 1080ti, running base Ubuntu 22.10 with no programs other than steam installed yet, both installed on a Samsung EVO NVME SSD.

Comment: Next time, [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1456521/edit) your question to add the details. This time I have done it for you, but don't do that next time.